# Avogadro's Number: 6.023 x 10^23 or 6.022 x 10^23?

Tags: mole

I was taught that Avogadro's number was $6.023 \cdot 10^{23}$. Now, the accepted value is allegedly $6.022 \cdot 10^{23}$. Has there been a change? If so, when and why? There are still some sites that use $6.023 \cdot 10^{23}$, so if this is wrong, why have those sites not been corrected?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant this gives it to a few further places and shows that it is 6.022 with rounding.

Answer (score 16):

Currently, the definition of Avogadro constant depends on the definition of the kilogram, and thus has an uncertainty. The recommended value<sup>[1][2]</sup> is

$$N_\pu{A} = \pu{6.022140857(74) \cdot 10^{23} mol-1}.$$

It will *probably* be fixed, however, coming May 20th, 2019 on World Metrology Day to exactly<sup>[3][4]</sup>

$$N_\pu{A}^{2019} = \pu{6.02214076 \cdot 10^{23} mol-1}.$$

See the references for a thorough review of the history, reasons for redefinition, how some relations become exact and others inexact, and to which degree, etc.

**References**

[1] Marquardt, R.; Meija, J.; Mester, Z.; Towns, M.; Weir, R.; Davis, R.; Stohner, J. 'A Critical Review of the Proposed Definitions of Fundamental Chemical Quantities and Their Impact on Chemical Communities (IUPAC Technical Report)'. *Pure and Applied Chemistry*, 2017, 89 (7), 951–981. DOI: [10.1515/pac-2016-0808](https://doi.org/10.1515/pac-2016-0808).

[2] Mohr, P. J.; Newell, D. B.; Taylor, B. N. 'CODATA Recommended Values of the Fundamental Physical Constants: 2014'. *Rev. Mod. Phys*., 2016, 88 (3), 035009. DOI: [10.1103/RevModPhys.88.035009](https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.88.035009).

[3] Marquardt, R.; Meija, J.; Mester, Z.; Towns, M.; Weir, R.; Davis, R.; Stohner, J. 'Definišion of the Mole (IUPAC Recommendation 2017)'. *Pure and Applied Chemistry*, 2018, 90 (1), 175–180. DOI: [10.1515/pac-2017-0106](https://doi.org/10.1515/pac-2017-0106).

[4] 'A new definition of the mole has arrived'. IUPAC press release. [archived link: goo.gl/5haPwJ](https://web.archive.org/web/20180303222007/https://iupac.org/new-definition-mole-arrived/)

Answer (score 4):

In fact it will get [updated](https://www.bipm.org/utils/en/pdf/CIPM/CIPM2017-EN.pdf?page=23) in the end of 2018. 
The new SI value will be updated to:[$6.02214076×10^{23} \text{mol}^{-1}$](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0026-1394/52/2/360)